# What are the returned data types from a Knex select() statement?

Tags: string, datetime, knex.js

*Hi everyone,*

I am currently using Knex.js for a project and a question arise when I make a `knex('table').select()` function call.

What are the **returned types** from the query ? In particular, If I have a **datetime** column in my table, what is the return value for this field ?

I believe the query will return a value of type `string` for this column. But it is the case for any database (I use SQLite3) ? It is possible that the query returns a `Date` value ?

EXAMPLE :

the user table has this schema :

```js
knex.schema.createTable('user', function (table) {
      table.increments('id');
      table.string('username', 256).notNullable().unique();
      table.timestamps(true, true);
  })
```

since I use SQLite3, `table.timestamps(true, true);` produces 2 datetime columns : created_at & modified_at.

when I make a query `knex('user').select()`, it returns a array of objects with the attributes : id, username, created_at, modified_at.

- id is of type `number`
- username is of type `string`
- what will be the types of created_at & modified_at ?

Will it be *always* of `string` type ? If I use an other database like PostgreSQL, these columns will have the `timestamptz` SQL type. The returned type of knex will be also a `string` type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not in fact something that Knex is responsible for, but rather the underlying database library. So if you're using SQLite, it would be `sqlite3`. If you're using Postgres, `pg` is responsible and you could find more documentation [here](https://node-postgres.com/features/types). Broadly, most libraries take the approach that types which have a direct JavaScript equivalent (booleans, strings, null, integers, etc.) are returned as those types; anything else is converted to a string.

Knex's job is to construct the SQL that the other libraries use to talk to the database, and receives the response that they return.

Comment: It is bit annoying, since knex is meant to be database-agnostic. Following your response, you can't expect the same result for your query depending the database. I know that knex is only a query builder, but it could make some garanties about the returned data type or a least specify what datatype is returned depending the database.

Comment: The documentation does contain quite a lot of platform-specific information: http://knexjs.org/#Schema-increments, for example. However it's more often concerned with type behaviour going into the database than coming out, to be sure. Most of the returned types are fairly predictable (if it's not a JS-supported type,
it'll likely be a string).

Answer (score 0):

as I believe it will be object of strings or numbers

Comment: for instance, you can't have booleans values ?

Comment: have you any references for your statement ?

Comment: @FrédéricLang you can as i saw in docs and i use right now https://knexjs.org/#Schema-boolean

Comment: Yes, so I think that Knex can actually return more types than only string and numbers

Comment: @FrédéricLang exactly most of types supported  by mysql